# Where is the network manager docklet in Docky in Meerkat?

Tags: 10.10, docky

Is there a network manager docklet shipped with Docky? If not, how can I add one?

Comment: Same problem here. On a fresh Ubuntu 10.10 install, I installed Docky 2.0.7-1 from the package manager and from docky-core/ppa. Neither version had a Network Manager docket (or anything similar).

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I've added the PPA and am running version 2.0.7. I don't have a network manager or volume docklet :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to find it in Docky Settings -> Docklets -> Network Manager. If it isn't mentioned there, then I would assume you need a newer version. You can try this stable PPA:
https://launchpad.net/~docky-core/+archive/stable

Or use the development PPA:
https://launchpad.net/~docky-core/+archive/ppa

The development PPA would be the most up-to-date one, but there's a higher risk of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docky/+bug/693251

> in docky 2.0.7 on Ubuntu 10.10,
>   there's no network manager docklet.

Rico Tzschichholz wrote on 2011-01-03:

> The network-manager docklet isn't
>   installed with the distribution
>   package due dependency limitations.

Comment: This has been apparently been resolved in the ppa that Ward mentions in his answer -- I've got the docklet and I'm running that ppa.